# Custom UITableViewCell from xib isn't displaying properly

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I've created custom UITableCells a bunch of times and I've never run into this problem, so I'm hoping you can help me find the thing I've missed or messed up. When I run my app, the cells in my table view appear to be standard cells with Default style.

I have SettingsTableCell which is a subclass of UITableViewCell. I have a SettingsTableCell.xib which contains a UITableViewCell and inside that are a couple labels and a textfield. I've set the class type in the xib to be SettingsTableCell and the File's Owner of the xib to my table controller.

My SettingsTableController has an IBOutlet property named tableCell. My cellForRowAtIndexPath contains the following code to load my table view xib and assign it to my table controller's tableCell property:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellSettings";

    SettingsTableCell *cell = (SettingsTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingsTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = self.tableCell;
        self.tableCell = nil;
        NSLog(@"cell=%@", cell);
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSArray *sections = [self.settingsDictionary objectForKey:KEY_GROUPS];

    NSDictionary *sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

    NSArray *itemsInSection = [sectionInfo objectForKey:KEY_FIELDS];

    NSDictionary *item = [itemsInSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:KEY_LABEL_NAME];
    cell.labelName.text = [item objectForKey:KEY_LABEL_NAME];
    cell.labelUnitsType.text = [item objectForKey:KEY_LABEL_UNITS];

    return cell;
}
```

This is what my xib set up looks like in IB:
[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder]

When I run my app, the table displays as if all of the cells are standard Default style cells though:
[image: Screenshot of my table view]

The seriously weird part is though... if I tap on the area of the cell where the textfield SHOULD be, the keyboard does come up! The textfield isn't visible, there's no cursor or anything like that... but it does respond. The visible UILabel is obviously not the UILabel from my xib though because the label in my xib is right justified and the one showing in the app is left justified.

I'm incredibly confused about how this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the code for my SettingsTableCell class:

```
@interface SettingsTableCell : UITableViewCell {

    UILabel *labelName;
    UILabel *labelUnitsType;
    UITextField *field;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelUnitsType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *field;

@end

#import "SettingsTableCell.h"


@implementation SettingsTableCell

@synthesize labelName;
@synthesize labelUnitsType;
@synthesize field;

- (void)dealloc {
    [labelName release];
    labelName = nil;
    [labelUnitsType release];
    labelUnitsType = nil;
    [field release];
    field = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: any chance you've found a solution for that since posting the question?

Comment: Not yet, I've been working on another project but plan to come back to this soon.

Comment: what i was trying to do, was create a custom uitableviewcell, add a label in it's bottom right, put some stuff on that label, **and** some stuff on the regular cell.textLabel from the superclass (UITableViewCell in that case). The "regular" text did appear and the custom label didn't. I fixed it by not using the cell.textLabel anymore and creating a custom label to fill that role as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't know **why**, but I do know that strange things happen while saving the cell in instance variables.

Have you tried loading the cell directly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

```
if (cell == nil) {
    topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNibName" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Your complete code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and SettingsTableCell.h/m would be of help.

Comment: Yes, I've tried loading the cell directly and skipping the IBOutlet method. I'll try your code snippet as well, just in case. I'll edit my original post to include my SettingsTableCell code.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought (probably wrong!) is that this is a z order issue and that the cells default label is being displayed on top of your text editing control. Hence not being able to see it. I'd guess that it still responds because the touch is being passed through by the label.

Just a guess :-)

Comment: Why would the original labels be there though? That's the part I don't get. I've done this 10 times before reading my cell in from a xib and it has always worked..